# Конфигурация устройств (аналогично диспетчеру устройств)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, com-port

Добрый день.
Скажите, какой функционал предпочтительнее для изменения параметров устройства (конкретно ком-порта).
Пока копаю в сторону SetupApi. С его помощью можно перечислить устройства, отфильтровать искомое по имени и вроде как получить и задать набор параметров.
Однако получается адское нагромождение кода, может есть что-то попроще?

[image: Скрин для примера]

Comment: CommConfigDialog вызывает штатное окно настроек порта

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, надо без окон

Comment: А, просто установить параметры? Тогда SetCommState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установка параметров COM-порта делается через `SetCommState()`. Отображение окна настроек - через `CommConfigDialog()`, но меняет ли она настройки я не знаю.